# Configure CORS for Azure Functions Local Host

Tags: azure, cors, azure-functions

I'm testing an Azure Functions app locally with the Azure Functions CLI tooling. Is there any way I can configure CORS settings for the local host?

Comment: Does a local instance not expose the same settings UI documented at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-azure-function-app-settings#manage-cors ?

Comment: no, you just host the runtime, not the portal

Comment: I’m completely unfamiliar with the architecture but you know that the only place where cross-origin/CORS restrictions are enforced is by browsers, on web apps running in browsers, right? So if this runtime that apps are executing in is outside the browser, then I’d assume nothing is preventing apps that run in it from making programmatic requests for any web URLs you want them to. So I guess I’m confused about what’s not working and what specific error you might be running into.

Comment: yes, my use case is a little unusual. it's running some JavaScript tests from the browser that automate calling my API. So the browser is calling out to localhost, but failing because of CORS.

Comment: Ah OK, there must be some config file for the web server on localhost? Or some source for it you can edit and then rebuild it from? Or is it just a binary that you don’t have the source for? Regardless, at the simplest level if you can access the config or source for it to make it send an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` response header, then the browser will allow your JavaScript tests to work as expected. (Now also curious to know that web server it actually runs on localhost… IIS?)

Comment: it's running this: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/tree/dev/src/WebJobs.Script.WebHost

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can start the host like this

```
func host start --cors *
```

You can also be more specific and provide a comma delimited list of allowed urls

More here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/1012

Comment: For me adding `,
  "Host": {
    "LocalHttpPort": 7071,
    "CORS": "*"
  }` to `local.settings.json` was easier  (suggested by someone in a deleted answer to this Q)

Comment: Yup, changing `local.settings.json` per the above fixed the problem for me (Windows 8.1, VS Code).  Anybody knows why this has to be in `local.settings.json`?  I already had the same setting in `host.json`, but that did not seem to work when developing locally.

Answer (score 100):

You can configure CORS in the [local settings file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local#local-settings-file) `local.settings.json`:

```
{
  "Values": {
  },
  "Host": {
    "CORS": "*"
  }
}
```

> Settings in the `local.settings.json` file are used only when you're
>   running projects locally

Comment: If you want to allow only a single domain it is important to not have a `/` at the end. So `http://localhost:4200/` does not work, but `http://localhost:4200` works as value of `CORS`.

Comment: Note that "Host" goes OUTSIDE of "Values". I tried to nest it inside, but this breaks things.

Comment: If you are passing authorization token then also include  `CORSCredentials: true` . Example  

```"Host": {
    "CORS": "https://localhost:3001",
    "CORSCredentials": true
  }```

Answer (score 5):

Another easy way to configure CORS on Azure Functions is to use Azure Portal,

1- Go to the Function App Settings in Azure Portal

[image]

2 - Click on CORS and add your local host url

[image]

And there you have it!!

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: The questions is specific for local development, not the one on Azure.

Comment: Is there a way to configure this in the code and not to have to do it via the azure web portal?

Comment: This seems insecure. You are telling the cloud to accept localhost from any computer out there. Hopefully you have other security in place as well to prevent that. Rather you would want to allow this on your local machine only.

Answer (score 2):

If you're having issues passing in the params via Visual Studio's Debug's "Application Arguments". This is how to pass the params from the command line:

1) Open an ordinary command prompt.

2) cd to your solution's compiled dll, i.e. "Your Solution Path"\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0

3) start the Azure function runtime from the command line, i.e.:

```
dotnet "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Azure.Functions.V2.Cli\func.dll" host start --port 7071 --cors * --pause-on-error
```

4) To debug in Visual Studio, Debug->Attach to Process.. and attach to the donet.exe that will be running.

Hope that helps prevent someone from banging their head too much...